# WPF CANVAS convert to Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, bitmap

I want to do something like this: I have a Canvas with a VisualBrush as background. This Canvas is too large to print it. I want to convert it in something like a Bitmap with given dpi and add it to a page for printing purpose. My question is:

> What is the best way to convert a Canvas in a bitmap like format, which i can add to a Page in WPF with given dpi?

Comment: You didn't search StackOverflow for something like "wpf print canvas"?

Comment: Oh i've done a lot of searching. The most common way i've found is: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339416/Printing-large-WPF-UserControls
Bit this way ( to convert a canvas) is a little bit strange. I'am particular interested in the converting and not in the printing process.

Comment: From the very first search result: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14153923/1136211.

Comment: So there is no better way than going through rendertargetbitmap and an encoder? I thought there would be a better solution. Png uses some discrete cos. transform to compress the data...it don't know why i should do this, if i need only the bitmap in a page. But thank you for this link!

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap is a bitmap. No need to encode it. The link should just give you an idea what to look for. It doesn't provide a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

1)- Convert your Convas to Writeablebitmap, look this :[The fastest way to convert canvas to the writeablebitmap in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050202/the-fastest-way-to-convert-canvas-to-the-writeablebitmap-in-wpf)

2) -Then Convert Writeablebitmap to any image, try this : [Converting WriteableBitmap to Bitmap in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298034/converting-writeablebitmap-to-bitmap-in-c-sharp)

You can make one method to this.

Comment: Except that there is no need for a conversion from RenderTargetBitmap to WriteableBitmap. RenderTargetBitmap is already a BitmapSource.

Comment: Certainly, but the most important is the solution itself